# Trying to use Redux for toggling a modal but it is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am fairly new to Redux in react. I am trying to use Redux to control modals displaying or not.

In my store/index.js file, I have kept it very simple:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const modalReducer = (state = { modal: false }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'visibility') {
    return {
      modal: state.modal + action.visibility,
    };
  }

  return state;
};

const store = createStore(modalReducer);

export default store;
```

In my src/index.js file, I wrap my App tag with the Provider tag:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

In my src/App.js file, I have both the values of "Modal" and "show" displaying what I want, which is either the string true or the string false:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ConsumerModal from './components/Modals/ConsumerModal';
import ConsumerModalContent from './components/Modals/ConsumerModalContent';

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const modal = useSelector((state) => state.modal);

  const modalHandler = (props) => {
    setShow(!modal);
    dispatch({ type: 'visibility', visibility: show });
    return show;
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {modal.toString()}
      {show.toString()}
      <ConsumerModal
        title='testing'
        content={<ConsumerModalContent />}
        onClose={modalHandler}
      ></ConsumerModal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which tells me that the redux is working as expected, but not in the className for the modal, which is what I want to control in the first place:

```
<div className={props.onClose ? 'Modal show' : 'Modal hide'}>
```

The class always reads as 'Modal show'

Comment: Did you try to provide `show={show}` to your `ConsumerModal` ? and then use `{props.show ? 'Modal show' : 'Modal hide'}`

Comment: @PixAff - yeah that works, but why didn't the modalHandler work? Do you think the state did not update in time via redux?

Comment: I guess, that props.onClose simply does not call your function. Let me make my comment an answer - so you can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform an `+` operator on bool values.

From what I understand about your use case, all you need is

```
if (action.type === 'visibility') {
    return {
      modal: action.visibility,
    };
}
```

Since, you just want to override previous value with whatever bool value is being dispatched.

Comment: yes, that is what I was doing wrong. Now, I removed the useState and no longer need to set "show" - I use only redux to control the state - thank you

Comment: Exactly, only redux state is needed. Glad to have helped. :)

Comment: Also I do not have to use props to pass the value of state back and forth. In the modal component - import selector - import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'; - define the selector - const modal = useSelector((state) => state.modal);  - then use the modal constant to toggle the state<div className={modal ? 'Modal show' : 'Modal hide'}> I will add this answer for future newbies and I have still checked your answer so that you will have the have the credit

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide `show={show}` to your ConsumerModal! And then use `{props.show ? 'Modal show' : 'Modal hide'}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nisanth Reddy, I have a more clear understanding, which has led to no longer needing to import useState or use props to pass the value. Redux can control state and have the values available in any component.

First, the correction in the src/store/index.js file:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const modalReducer = (state = { modal: true }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'visibility') {
    return {
      modal: !action.visibility,
    };
  }

  return state;
};

const store = createStore(modalReducer);

export default store;
```

BTW, modal is set to true, so that I could see the modal when the app first loads, so that I could test the close button to close the modal

Second, the src/App.js file, was changed to the following, because I no longer need to manage the state in the file or pass the props:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.scss';
import './components/Modals/Modals.scss';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import ConsumerModal from './components/Modals/ConsumerModal';
import ConsumerModalContent from './components/Modals/ConsumerModalContent';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const modal = useSelector((state) => state.modal);

  const modalHandler = (props) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'visibility', visibility: modal });
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {modal.toString()}
      <ConsumerModal
        title='testing'
        content={<ConsumerModalContent />}
        onClose={modalHandler}
      ></ConsumerModal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Third, I import the selector so that I can pass the value of modal to the modal component:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ConsumerModal = (props) => {
  const modal = useSelector((state) => state.modal);

  return (
    <div className={modal ? 'Modal show' : 'Modal hide'}>
      <span className='ModalContent'>
        <span onClick={props.onClose} className='BtnClose'>
          <span>Close</span>
        </span>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        {props.content}
        <nav>
          <span onClick={props.onClose} className='BtnGreen'>
            Close
          </span>
        </nav>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConsumerModal;
```

[image: First screen shot displays the modal with a class of 'Modal show']
[image: Second screen shot is the modal set to 'Modal hide' in the class]

SECOND EDIT - Because I needed to track more than one modal, I discovered reduxjs/toolkit, which allows for multiple slices and multiple functions(actions), along with allowing intellisense to function within the IDE.

In this example, this works for the consumer modal, but there will surely be many other modals and they cannot all have the same state of visibility. Also, to me, this way seems to be easier to manage a complex application.

```
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit
```

The following is the src/store/index.js refactored:

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialStateCnsmrModal = { visibility: true };

const cnsmrModalSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cnsmrModal',
  initialState: initialStateCnsmrModal,
  reducers: {
    visibility(state) {
      state.visibility = !state.visibility;
    },
  },
});

const initialStatePolicyModal = { visibility: true };

const policyModalSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'policyModal',
  initialState: initialStatePolicyModal,
  reducers: {
    visibility(state) {
      state.visibility = !state.visibility;
    },
  },
});

const initialStateAuth = { isLoggedIn: false };

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: initialStateAuth,
  reducers: {
    login(state) {
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
  },
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cnsmrModal: cnsmrModalSlice.reducer,
    policyModal: policyModalSlice.reducer,
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
  },
});

export const cnsmrModalActions = cnsmrModalSlice.actions;
export const policyModalActions = policyModalSlice.actions;

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default store;
```

The following is the src/App.js refactored:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.scss';
import './components/Modals/Modals.scss';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { cnsmrModalActions, policyModalActions } from './store/index';
import ConsumerModal from './components/Modals/ConsumerModal';
import ConsumerModalContent from './components/Modals/ConsumerModalContent';
import PolicyModal from './components/Modals/PolicyModal';
import PolicyModalContent from './components/Modals/PolicyModalContent';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cnsmrModal = useSelector((state) => state.cnsmrModal.visibility);
  const plcyModal = useSelector((state) => state.policyModal.visibility);

  const cnsmrModalHandler = () => {
    dispatch(cnsmrModalActions.visibility());
  };

  const policyModalHandler = () => {
    dispatch(policyModalActions.visibility());
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='test-flexbox'>
        <span className='row'>consumer</span>
        {cnsmrModal.toString()}
        <span className='row'>policy</span>
        {plcyModal.toString()}
      </div>
      <ConsumerModal
        title='testing'
        content={<ConsumerModalContent />}
        onClose={cnsmrModalHandler}
      ></ConsumerModal>
      <PolicyModal
        title='my policy'
        content={<PolicyModalContent />}
        onClose={policyModalHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The following is the src/components/modals/ConsumerModal.js refactored:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ConsumerModal = (props) => {
  const cnsmrModal = useSelector((state) => state.cnsmrModal.visibility);

  return (
    <div className={cnsmrModal ? 'Modal show' : 'Modal hide'}>
      <span className='ModalContent'>
        <span onClick={props.onClose} className='BtnClose'>
          <span>Close</span>
        </span>
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        {props.content}
        <nav>
          <span onClick={props.onClose} className='BtnGreen'>
            Close
          </span>
        </nav>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConsumerModal;
```

The following is the src/components/modals/policyModal.js refactored:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PolicyModal = (props) => {
  const plcyModal = useSelector((state) => state.policyModal.visibility);
  return (
    <div
      className={
        plcyModal ? 'Modal show policy-modal' : 'Modal hide policy-modal'
      }
    >
      <span className='ModalContent'>
        <span onClick={props.onClose} className='BtnClose'>
          <span>Close</span>
        </span>
        <h2>
          Projekt MK6 <em>e</em>Documents <span>(Auto Policy #12345678)</span>
        </h2>
        {props.content}
        <nav>
          <span onClick={props.onClose} className='BtnGreen'>
            Close
          </span>
        </nav>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PolicyModal;
```

With this code, now I can also have a policy modal, a terms and conditions modal, a survey modal, etc... All with their own defined slice. One for each modals, one for authentication, one for a cart, etc... While also having multiple functions within each slice.

[image: As you can see by the screenshot, both modals function seperately]